# Create a continuous variable not related to binary target

Tags: correlation, simulation, synthetic-data

I would like to create a continuous variable in such a way that it has least predictive information with respect to binary target variable.

That continuous variable needs to have good relationship with another binary variable. Is there a way to do this in R or SAS?

Comment: What do you mean by `least predictive information`? Do you mean that the $r$ is 0 or that the regression (in predicting the binary var by the continuous and the other binary) $b$ is 0. Or something else?

Comment: I mean that when I perform logistic regression using this continuous variable as independent variable and binary target as dependent, I should get nonsignificant result for beta = 0 indicating weak relationship between the two variables.

Comment: At the same time this continuous variable should be highly correlated with another binary independent variable with the condition that this binary variable has a high significance in a univariate logistic regression with the binary target as dependent.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the effect of correlation on automatic variable selection procedures of logistic regression where variables are correlated and some are not at all predictive of target but some are highly predictive of target.